# Rails: Order array by number of child objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, parent-child

I have an array of `posts`. I want to order this array of `posts` by number of `comments` they have (First object in the array being most comments, last being the least). A `Post` has many `comments`. This seems like a simple problem, but I can't figure out how to order them. I've tried and I don't believe it's possible to achieve this via the `order` method. Is there a Rails method I don't know about? Or will I have to home roll it? Thanks in advance!

PS: My relation of comments to posts is polymorphic `Comment` - (`belongs_to :threadable`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a complicated active record query, however, the easiest thing by far is to just add a `:counter_cache` on association. You just add a field on your Post model called `comments_count` and then in your Comment model:

```
belongs_to :post, counter_cache: true
```

Then since it's just a column like all your other columns you can order by it.

See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

Comment: Thanks guys, but one issue, my relation is polymorphic. (belongs to threadable). How do I go about this?

Comment: `belongs_to :threadable, polymorphic: true, counter_cache: true` Just makes sure you add `comments_count` to each threadable Class.

Comment: The link I provided gives you all the information you need on how these associations work. It's worth a read.

Comment: Thank you very much sir. I'm surprised I've never heard about this. The more you learn....

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this would probably be using the `counter_cache` option

see:

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#counter-cache
- http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column

-

```
class Comment
  belongs_to :post, counter_cache: true
end
```

add the column `comments_count` to the posts database table, then order by that

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve it is to use counter cache feature. You need to add integer column to your `posts` table called `comments_count`. Then on your comments model you need to change your `post` association to read:

```
 belongs_to :post, counter_cache: true
```

Rails will handle comments_count column to show how many comments are associated with given post. You can then use this column for ordering.